# Multiplying matrices in python, error in raw_input's

Tags: python, matrix, raw-input

I would like to create a program that multiplies two matrices given by the user. I want the user to enter the rows of the 1st matrix, and then I want to save each row in a dictionary, with the dictionary keys being the number of the row. Nevertheless, when I make raw_input to ask the user the `ith` row, I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

This is my code:

```
print "this program computes the product of two square matrices with real entries"
n = raw_input("Enter number of columns=Number of rows")
rowsofmatrix1={}
columnsofmatrix2={}
for i in range (1,n+1):
   rowsofmatrix1[i]=raw_input("Enter row number"+str(i)+"of the first matrix as a list")
for j in range (1,n+1):
   columnsofmatrix2[j]=raw_input("Enter column number"+str(j)+"of the second matrix as a list")
print rowsofmatrix1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert n in order to use it in the range function. Try to change to the code below:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter number of columns=Number of rows"))
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't realised... I guess I'll just put input instead of raw_input. Thanks